# How to create an outbound API call from SFMC using SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

Use Case - get data from external web services and store the data (response) inside SMFC data extension field.

*New to API Calls - detailed step by step guidance would be really helpful.

The approach i'd like to take is to use SSJS + Automation Studio

Comment: The scope of your question's extremely broad. First try looking at SSJS documentation online https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm. Review Content Syndication Functions - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationFunctions.htm and understand the Core and Platform functions you can use to update data extensions. Then, when you've got stuck, post your question and any associated error messages (use try...catch).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Macca as it is also not clear what you try to get. The question is so vague that you cannot expect an answer to be helpful. However, to give you an idea, here is how I would do it:

1. Use Script.Util.HttpRequest(url) to retrieve whatever content from your external web service
2. format the response in the data structure you need
3. insert into a data extension

You should read into WSProxy - createBatch.

If you explain your request in more detail and show what you have done so far, you may get more detailed help.